# Fill in NAs using mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, na, fillna, mutate

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

v1 = c(1 , NA, 3, 5, NA, NA, 2, 12, NA, 5, NA, 0, 1, 2, 6, 8)
alt = rnorm(length(v1), 0, 1)
tb = tibble(v1, alt)

print(tb)

A tibble: 16 × 2
      v1     alt
   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1  0.495 
 2    NA  0.726 
 3     3  0.667 
 4     5  0.955 
 5    NA -1.68  
 6    NA -1.21  
 7     2 -1.96  
 8    12  1.47  
 9    NA  0.372 
10     5  1.07  
11    NA  0.531 
12     0  0.102 
13     1  1.34  
14     2  0.0872
15     6 -0.391 
16     8 -0.250
```

I need to fill `NAs` in `v1` using the mutate. The idea is that when there is one `NA` in `v1`, it will be filled by the multiplication between the variable `alt` and the value of `v1` prior to the NA.

I solve this using loop `for`, but this may take time to depend on the data set.

```
for (i in 1:length(v1)) {
  if( is.na(tb[i, 'v1']) ){
    tb[i, 'v1'] = tb[i-1, 'v1']*tb[i, 'alt']
  }
}
```

This yields:

```
A tibble: 16 × 2
       v1     alt
    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  1      0.495 
 2  0.726  0.726 
 3  3      0.667 
 4  5      0.955 
 5 -8.38  -1.68  
 6 10.1   -1.21  
 7  2     -1.96  
 8 12      1.47  
 9  4.47   0.372 
10  5      1.07  
11  2.65   0.531 
12  0      0.102 
13  1      1.34  
14  2      0.0872
15  6     -0.391 
16  8     -0.250
```

My question is: How do I fill `NAs` using my condition and `mutate` or others `dplyr` verbs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `cumprod`:

```
tb %>%
  group_by(id = cumsum(!is.na(v1))) %>%
  mutate(v1 = v1[1]*cumprod(alt^is.na(v1)))

# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   id [11]
       v1     alt    id
    <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
 1  1      0.495      1
 2  0.726  0.726      1
 3  3      0.667      2
 4  5      0.955      3
 5 -8.4   -1.68       3
 6 10.2   -1.21       3
 7  2     -1.96       4
 8 12      1.47       5
 9  4.46   0.372      5
10  5      1.07       6
11  2.66   0.531      6
12  0      0.102      7
13  1      1.34       8
14  2      0.0872     9
15  6     -0.391     10
16  8     -0.25      11
```

In Base R:

```
prd <- function(a, b){
  ifelse(is.na(a), prd(b * c(1,head(a,-1)),b), a)
}


transform(tb, v1 = prd(v1, alt))
       v1     alt
1   1.000  0.4950
2   0.726  0.7260
3   3.000  0.6670
4   5.000  0.9550
5  -8.400 -1.6800
6  10.164 -1.2100
7   2.000 -1.9600
8  12.000  1.4700
9   4.464  0.3720
10  5.000  1.0700
11  2.655  0.5310
12  0.000  0.1020
13  1.000  1.3400
14  2.000  0.0872
15  6.000 -0.3910
16  8.000 -0.2500
```

Answer (score 3):

Something closer to what you are looking for is:

```
tb %>%
   mutate(v1 = unlist(accumulate2(v1, alt[-1], ~if(is.na(..2))..3*..1 else ..2)))

# A tibble: 16 x 2
       v1     alt
    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  1      0.495 
 2  0.726  0.726 
 3  3      0.667 
 4  5      0.955 
 5 -8.4   -1.68  
 6 10.2   -1.21  
 7  2     -1.96  
 8 12      1.47  
 9  4.46   0.372 
10  5      1.07  
11  2.66   0.531 
12  0      0.102 
13  1      1.34  
14  2      0.0872
15  6     -0.391 
16  8     -0.25
```